Не работает роутинг в Next.js
Всем привет! Я делал сайт по курсу 3 летней давности и столкнулся с проблемой. Во 1 отсутствовала папка pages, ноя разобрался и стал делать страницы в app. Но там работает только со страницами под названием page. Остальное не рендерится.
Вот папка app:
app
 tracks
    create
      page.tsx           
      [id].tsx           
    page.tsx             
favicon.ico
globals.css              
layout.tsx               
page.module.css          
page.tsx 


Скорее всего дело не в папках, а в написанном коде

В next так и задумано.. Вот пример с документации.  Если внутри папки есть page.js то это страница.

